# Add several addresses programatically into a google map

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-maps-api-3

I have a ASP.NET MVC 4 application.

Let's say I have 4 records from my db that has a field address.

**Q:** How can I send this addresses to a google maps control(or directly to the maps.google.com website) ?
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the first adress as `saddr`-parameter(start-address) and the other 3, separated by `+to:` as `daddr`-parameter(destination-address)

[http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=strasbourg,france&daddr=troyes,france+to:paris,france+to:nantes,france](http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=strasbourg,france&daddr=troyes,france%20to%3aparis,france%20to%3anantes,france)

**description of the parameters:** http://www.seomoz.org/ugc/everything-you-never-wanted-to-know-about-google-maps-parameters